# An association from the table CountryList refers to an unmapped class

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am getting the exception

> Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table CountryList refers to an unmapped class: com.abegaa.model.StateListPojo

for the hibernate Mapping between for this two hbm file

1st one CountryList and StateList

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com.abegaa.model">

 <class name="CountryListPojo" table="CountryList">
 <id name="Id" column="Id">
 <generator class="increment"></generator>
  </id>

 <many-to-one name="Db_CountryId" column="Db_CountryId" class="StateListPojo"></many-to-one>

  <property name="Db_CountryName" column="Db_CountryName"></property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.abegaa.model">
  <class name="StateListPojo" table="StateList">

 <id name="Id" column="Id">
 <generator class="increment"></generator></id>

 <set name="Db_CountryId">
    <key column="Db_CountryId"></key>
<one-to-many class="CountryListPojo"/>
  </set>

  <property name="Db_StateId" column="Db_StateId"/>
  <property name="Db_StateName" column="Db_StateName"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and this is my classes.

```
public class CountryListPojo
{

       private long Id;
private String Db_CountryId;
private String Db_CountryName;
    //get and set
} 

 public class StateListPojo 
{

private String Id;
private String Db_CountryId;
private String Db_StateId,Db_StateName;
 //get and set
 }
```

I can't understand where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: 1) Please use  correct Java naming convention.

2) there is no reference  to any Set. 

Set<CountryListPojo>

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
public class CountryListPojo
{

   private long Id;
   private String Db_CountryId;
   private String Db_CountryName;
   private Set<StateListPojo > stateListPojos = new HashSet<StateListPojo ();
//get and set
}

public class StateListPojo 
{

    private String Id;
    CountryListPojo Db_CountryId = new CountryListPojo();
    private String Db_StateId,Db_StateName;
    //get and set
 }
```

and hbm should have

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
       "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

 <hibernate-mapping package="com.abegaa.model">

  <class name="CountryListPojo" table="CountryList">
      <id name="Id" column="Id">
        <generator class="increment"></generator>
      </id>
    <property name="Db_CountryName" column="Db_CountryName"></property>
    <set name="stateListPojos">
         <key><column name="Db_CountryId" /></key>
         <one-to-many class="StateListPojo" />
     </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
     "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
        <hibernate-mapping package="com.abegaa.model">
            <class name="StateListPojo" table="StateList">

              <id name="Id" column="Id">
                  <generator class="increment"></generator>
              </id>
              <many-to-one class="CountryListPojo" name="Db_CountryId">
                  <column name="Db_CountryId"></column>
               </many-to-one>
              <property name="Db_StateId" column="Db_StateId"/>
              <property name="Db_StateName" column="Db_StateName"/>
           </class>
       </hibernate-mapping>
```